# Rename file in Amazon Glacier

Tags: amazon-glacier

Is it possible to rename an archive in Amazon Glacier?

The [documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/working-with-archives.html) says:

> After you upload an archive, you cannot update its content or its
>   description. The only way you can update the archive content or its
>   description is by deleting the archive and uploading another archive.

That would lead me to think that it's not possible, but I'm not sure whether the file name is considered part of the archive *description*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, the file name is part of the archive *content*, therefore you can't update it.

Answer (score 4):

No, as the file name usually stored as part of archive *description* (depends on your client).

Comment: Almost exact duplicate of @MichaelHampton 's answer, 1 year later :)

Comment: I think it's opposite to @MichaelHampton answer.

Comment: Is it? I'd be surprised that how the file name is stored *depends on the client*...

Comment: MichaelHampton suggests that filename is part of archive *content*, while it's usually part of archive *description*. Words *content* and *description* are highlighted in original post and MichaelHampton answer. It's different things. Also Amazon Glacier does not have specification for how filenames should be stored, so it depends on client.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that... +1 for you then!